# Почему не работает регулярное выражение в JS, когда оно работает в PHP?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Почему не работает регулярное выражение в JS, когда оно работает в PHP?

```
var re = /^[a-z0-9-.]{1,39}+$/;
```

из-за знака `+` происходит ошибка синтаксиса:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-z0-9-.]{1,39}+$/: Nothing to repeat
```

Но почему? Регулярное выражение правильное же!

Comment: Два квантификатора подряд после символьного класса не имеют смысла. То, что оно работает в PHP не делает последнему чести.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev  о чём речь?

Comment: О квантификаторах. Термин довольно распространенный, расписывать что это такое не хочу.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev о чём речь? Что такое квантификаторы я знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что диалект регулярных выражений JavaScript не поддерживает данного поведения регулярных выражений PHP.

Comment: после группы тоже работает, я имею ввиду `()` а не `[]`

Comment: `[]` - это символьный класс, а не группа

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, спасибо, поправил ответ.

Comment: а к чему из перечисленного _одного символа, класса символов или символьного класса в квадратных скобках_ относятся круглые скобки?

Comment: @cheops, я немного подправил ваш ответ. возможно так он будет чуть более понятным. Если не согласны с моей правкой -- её всегда можно откатить =)

Comment: Ставлю минус. Абсолютно неверный ответ.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Вы заблуждаетесь

Comment: @cheops рекомендую к удалению

Comment: @ReinRaus, да, похоже вы правы

Comment: @ReinRaus, я бы и рад удалить, но он принят, SO не позволяет удалять такие ответы, я самостоятельно смогу его удалить только если Юрий Светлов снимет зеленую галку.

Comment: Вынужден откорректировать свой ответ.

Comment: Снял минус, но тут правильнее говорить, что не ПХП расширен, а JS не полностью реализует возможности PCRE

Comment: PCRE как бы Perl-регулярные выражения (по хорошему языки и не обязаны их реализовывать), до недавнего времени стандартом были и остаются POSIX-регулярные выражения. Хотя этот тот случай, когда Perl-регулярные выражения де-факто являются стандартом.

Comment: Просто регулярки в JS позиционируют себя как PCRE, JS не дотягивает до PCRE, а не PCRE улучшен относительно LS ^)

Answer (score 7):

В книгах такое поведение назывется "сверхжадным" квантификатором, которое не поддерживается движком JavaScript, но поддерживается в PHP.
Это такое поведение квантификатора, когда ни один захваченный литерал не буден откачен назад при несовпадении. Может произойти откат только всей конструкции в целом.

Проще всего прийти к пониманию вопроса прочитав про "атомарную группировку".

Выражение

```
[a-z0-9-.]{1,39}+
```

Эквивалентно

```
(?>[a-z0-9-.]{1,39})
```

Вот еще небольшой список "сверхжадных" квантификаторов PCRE:

```
++
*+
?+
{m,n}+
```

их все отличает наличие `+` после самого квантификатора.

---

Смотрим примеры поведения:
https://regex101.com/r/nO7rE6/6

```
a++a
```

Нет совпадения, потому что сверхжадная квантификация не вернет ни одного захваченного литерала несмотря на то, что из-за этого все выражение не совпадет.

https://regex101.com/r/nO7rE6/5

```
a+a
```

Квантификация вернет один литерал, потому что это нужно для общего совпадения.

https://regex101.com/r/nO7rE6/4

```
a+?a
```

а тут идет попытка захватить минимальное число литералов для общего совпадения.